# How to send notifications to GCM using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-messaging

I'm searching for a way to send push notifications to devices from my django project. I want to send push notifications using pure python, with out third packages like django-gcm or python-gcm.

Answer (score 0):

It is just an HTTP request to an endpoint. The docs explain how to use it. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream